# Changing the color of open form

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-2.0

I have an application where in the end user can change the color of the form, textboxes, labels, buttons during run time. Let us say that if a form is opened and the user has changed the form color from blue to green. To affect the color settings the existing form has to be closed and re-opened as I'm setting the form color in the Form_Load event. I saw many applications where-in the changes of color would apply to all open forms, buttons, labels etc.

Kindly suggest me appropriate methods to achieve dynamic form coloring.
Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: is it something still unclear?

Answer (score 1):

You change the form's `BackColor`. Any need to reopen the form.

Change the Backcolor of the form, and recursively the childs, à la:

```
// forms background color
this.BackColor = yourNewColor

// controls background color
foreach c Control in this.Controls
 c.BackColor = yourColor
```

Comment: Use recursion in your case, because controls can contain other controls.. :)

Comment: @igor: I leave OP doing it by itself, as training.